# Cypress iterating through elements to click on, bad practice?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

In my scenario, I am clicking on a  dropdown selection, which yields the child elements to be clicked on. I am wanting to click on the first element/option, here's my approach which is working.

```
cy.get( 'ul[role="listbox"]' ).children().each(( $btn, index ) => {
      
      // clicks first option in dropdown
      if( index === 0 ) {
         cy.get( $btn ).click();
      }
          
    });
```

The reason I'm doing it like this, is when I try to click directly on the element without iterating through the children, I'll sometimes get the error "cy.click()` failed because this element is detached from the DOM."

But the way I have it implemented now, the error does not occur.

HTML for the dropdown (has 2 options in this case, can be any amount):

```
<div role="listbox" class="hd"> 
    <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" data-baseweb="menu" id="bui-3" aria-multiselectable="false" class="dc au b4 b3 b5 ba he hf ay az dd de df dg h8 cv dr hg">
        <li role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" id="bui-5" class="ae e2 ag ga au e5 hl e9 ao hi ei d7 b3 he hf hj hk dr">
            <div aria-selected="false" class="e9 ag">Dropdown Option 1 </div>
        </li>
        <li role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" id="bui-6" class="ae e2 ag ga au e5 hl e9 ao hi ei d7 b3 he hf hj hk dr">
            <div aria-selected="false" class="e9 ag">Dropdown Option 2 </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your dropdown? I don't think you should be getting that error, but can't put my finger on why you are without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Added the HTML to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried finding the first `li`, using Cypress' `.find()` command? I would guess that this would work *and hopefully not give you the error message described.*

```js
cy.get( 'ul[role="listbox"]' )
  .find('li') // searches for all `li` underneath the yielded element
  .eq(0) // selects the item at the index
  .click();
```

Comment: This is probably the best approach, thanks. Hopefully the error does not continue to happen.